# Align Boostrap Anchor Button with Text at the Bottom inside FigCaption

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align two anchor buttons next to each other with text below each button. I am doing this in a figcaption as the button should display only when the user hovers over the image. However I am not even getting close.

here's what I have tried so far:

```
<div class="row cs-style-3">
   <div class="col-lg-4 gitem">

   </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 gitem">
              <figure>
                  <img src="pictures/cover/book-2015.png" alt="">
                  <figcaption class="text-center">
                      <div class="row">
                          <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>Download </a><br />
                          <p>PDF file</p>
                          <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>Download</a>
                          <p>Zip file</p>
                      </div>
                  </figcaption>

              </figure>            
      </div>


   <div class="col-lg-4 gitem">

   </div>



</div><!-- end row -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put each button and text pair in an own column

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
     <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>Download </a><br />
     <p>PDF file</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
     <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>Download</a>
     <p>Zip file</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked for me without any extra css.

Comment: be aware that col-lg- only applies to larger screens. 
You can use col-xs- to apply it to all

Answer (score 0):

Try this code . it would be better if we have you css as well .
http://jsfiddle.net/2s1g7oLe/

html

```
<div class="row cs-style-3">
<div class="col-lg-4 gitem"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 gitem">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://jolka.qwqw.hu/tarhely/jolka/kepek/201406/konyvek10.png" alt="">
        <figcaption class="text-center" >
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>Download </a>

                <br />
                <p>PDF file</p> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6"><a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>Download</a>

                <p>Zip file</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 gitem"></div>
</div>
<!-- end row -->
```

And the simple CSS

```
figcaption 
{
 display:none
}
figure  
{
text-align:center
}

figure:hover figcaption
{
display:block;
}
```